# C++ create an input stream manipulator to mask output but keep all input intact

Tags: c++

what i am trying to do is to create a steam manipulator for `cin` that will take user input as usual, but on screen it won't show specific characters, instead will print `*`. For example, if i use the manipulator like this- `cin >> convspace >> buffer;` where `convspace` is the manipulator, `buffer` is an `std::string`. Now if i run the program, it will obviously ask for input, but as i start typing it will show the characters i am typing. I want to manipulate that. I want it to print `*` if i press a space, but keep the space for the `buffer` as well. So if i type - `Hello World`, the prompt should print `Hello*World` instead but will set `buffer` to `Hello World`. I started with the following code, but then i got stuck, i don't know what to do now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class space_filter_buffer : public streambuf
{
public:
    space_filter_buffer( streambuf* src )
        : buffer( src )
    {
        // reset input buffer to use one char and initially
        // consider the buffer as full
        setg( &c, &c + 1, &c + 1 );
    }

    traits_type::int_type underflow()
    {
        traits_type::int_type ch;
        ch = buffer->sbumpc();
        if ( traits_type::not_eof( ch ) )
        {
            c = traits_type::to_char_type( ch );
            // convert spaces into *
            if ( c == ' ' )
            {
                c = '*';
            }

            // make one read position available
            setg( &c, &c, &c + 1 );
        }
        return ch;
    }

private:
    streambuf* buffer;
    traits_type::char_type c;
};

istream&
convspace( istream& in )
{
    in.rdbuf( new space_filter_buffer { in.rdbuf() } );
    return in;
}

int
main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    string data;
    cin >> convspace >> data;
    cout << data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or direction.

Comment: Not possible in standard C++. What you are talking about is the *echoing* of characters in the console, and that isn't under C++ control.

Comment: i was hoping to manipulate `tie()` as well to control the output.

Comment: `tie` causes an output stream to be flushed before an input stream is read. It has nothing to do with the echoing of **input** characters to the console, which is more of a device driver thing.